# get all groups of user with other user object properties

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell and wanted to learn how to get the groups belonging to a user as well as other user object properties in the format below (repeating the user and email for each group):

```
username user_email        user_groups
user1   user1@domain.com   group1
user1   user1@domain.com   group2
user1   user1@domain.com   group3
user2   user2@domain.com   group1
user2   user2@domain.com   group2
...
```

I understand that this gets the groups of a user but unsure of how to include other user objects and have it repeated in the above format:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership username | select name
```

Comment: How are you getting your users? Meaning which users are you after?

Comment: looking to get all users by using Get-ADUser in ou and saving that in an array object and loop @DougMaurer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to get your ADUser objects, expand their memberof property, iterate through those, and get the ad group of each.

```
$username = "PowerShellGuy"
$adUserObj = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$username'" -properties memberof
$groups = $adUserObj.MemberOf | Get-ADgroup
```

You can one-line it like this

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq 'PowerShellGuy'" -properties memberof | % memberof | Get-ADgroup
```

If you want custom formatting, you can build a custom psobject, or a custom class. I prefer the class method

```
Class CustomAdInfo 
{
    $UserName
    $Email
    $Group
}
```

If you want one group per, then you can do something like this

```
Class CustomAdInfo 
{
    $UserName
    $Email
    $Group
}

$listOfUsers = @("foo","bar")

$customObjects = 
    foreach($user in $listOfUsers)
    {
        $adUserObj = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$user'" -properties memberof, emailaddress
        $groups = $adUserObj.MemberOf | Get-ADgroup
        foreach($group in $groups)
        {
            New-Object -TypeName CustomAdInfo -Property @{
                UserName = $adUserObj.SamAccountName
                Email = $adUserObj.EmailAddress
                Group = $group
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: is there a way to export this to CSV as well?

Comment: @just4code Yep, just pipe `$customObjects` to `Export-Csv` like this `$customObjects | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture -Path "C:\temp\thingy.csv"`

Comment: Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

No reason to overcomplicate it. I've added the Get-ADOU call in case you want to use the name of the group instead of the distinguished name.

```
$ouname = "Some OU"

$OU = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "name -eq '$ouname'"

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase $OU -Properties mail | Foreach-Object {
    Foreach($group in Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $_)
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            UserName   = $_.samaccountname
            User_Email = $_.mail
            User_Group = $group.name
        }
    }
}
```